# Rust multiple lifetimes struct can't access beyond the less longer lifetime parameter

Tags: struct, rust, lifetime

```rust
struct TwoStrRef<'a, 'b> {
    str1: &'a str,
    str2: &'b str,
}

fn main() {
    let a_ref_struct;
    let string_1 = String::from("hello");
    let str_ref;
    {
        let string_2 = String::from("world");

        a_ref_struct = TwoStrRef {
            str1: &string_1,
            str2: &string_2,
        };

        str_ref = a_ref_struct.str1;
    }

    // str_ref; // Ok

    // a_ref_struct.str1;  // Error: `string_2` does not live long enough borrowed value does not live long enough
}
```

there are two lifetime parameters for `struct TwoStrRef`, `a'` and `'b`, and I assign the reference of `string_1` and `string_2` (which are in different scope and `string_1` is the longer one) to field `str_1` and `str_2`, and when I try to access `a_ref_struct.str1` outside the scope of `string_2` (but the same with `string_1`), the compiler will throw error, which indicated that `string_2` does not live long enough.  Isn't the `str1` field holds the reference of `string_1` that is not outside its scope ?  And why if I assign the str1 reference to `str_ref`, I can access it in the same scope with `string_1`?

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't the `str1` field holds the reference of `string_1` that is not outside its scope ?

`a_ref_struct` is dropped *before* `string_2` goes out of scope: this is required because otherwise any access of its `str2` field (which could potentially occur in its drop handler, for example) would be invalid.  Indeed if `a_ref_struct` were to exist after `string2` is dropped, its `str2` would be a reference into released memory which is Undefined Behaviour even if that reference is never accessed.

> And why if I assign the str1 reference to `str_ref`, I can access it in the same scope with `string_1`?

There you are just taking a copy of the reference that is held in `a_ref_struct.str1` (with lifetime `'a` of `string_1`) and storing that copy into `str_ref`.  `a_ref_struct` can then be (and is) dropped without affecting that (copied) reference.